# Updating vue library to vue 3 using vue-next

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to upgrade a library I made to vue3, using the vue cli with `vue add vue-next`, but I get the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPwcB.png)

I removed nodemodule and installed it again, and I removed the vue-template-compiler, because it doesn't work with vue3, but it still gives me this error.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Update: I removed `vue-template-compiler` and now it gives me this error:

```
[!] Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler'
Require stack:
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler\dist\compiler.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler\dist\index.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup-plugin-vue\dist\rollup-plugin-vue.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\build\rollup.config.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup\dist\bin\rollup
Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler'
Require stack:
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler\dist\compiler.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler\dist\index.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup-plugin-vue\dist\rollup-plugin-vue.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\build\rollup.config.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js
- C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup\dist\bin\rollup
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler\dist\compiler.js:26:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js:516:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler\dist\index.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\projects\UTT-Message-System\module\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\loadConfigFile.js:516:13)
```

Comment: Please, never post pictures of code. Post code itself. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Copying over the text of the error will make it easier for people to see it, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67921043/edit) to include it.

Comment: Did you try following the advice given by the first error?

Comment: I erased everything and started over, but i still have the same error for some reason, It cant be upgraded to vue3